# Photoshop 2022: Can't change default color profile for new documents (Defaults to Don't Color Manage this Document)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-profile

Here's a screenshot of my new document window:

[image: New Document Window]

Notice under Advanced that the default is `Don't Color Manage this Document`. I want to change this to ensure that sRGB is default.

Before you ask, I have changed the working space to sRGB. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Color Settings]

How can I accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For *new* documents it *should* stay set at whatever the *last used setting* was. Are you saying for every new document it resets? If you open a new document, set it to sRGB and click OK... then open *another* new document, is it *not* set to sRGB? (Of course you can always create a **preset** with whatever settings you want). (Note **new** documents. Existing documents use whatever was set last time the file was saved.)

Comment: @Scott Yep, that's what's happening. The color profile reverts back to unmanaged even after creating a document with a sRGB profile. I can't get the change to stick.

Comment: Reset pref maybe.. This is more technical support and kind of off-topic here.